# Environment Variable Empty in Bash Script

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-linux-2

I have an EC2 instance that I am deploying on AWS.

I am using an Amazon Linux 2, and I am passing a user data to it as such:

```
userdata_file.write(
        f'''
        #!/bin/bash\n
        export PAGERDUTYAPIKEY='mykey'\n
        sudo yum install git -y\n
        chmod +x ./basic_test.sh \n
        echo $PAGERDUTYAPIKEY> /home/ec2-user/pagerdutyapikey1.txt\n
        sudo ./basic_test.sh
        '''.strip()
    )
```

basic_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "s/enterpagerdutyapikey/${PAGERDUTYAPIKEY}/g" > path.txt
```

However, when i run it, in the `path.txt` it is echoing as such:

```
s/enterpagerdutyapikey//g
```

But when i ssh in the server and run the same bash script, it echos as such:

```
s/enterpagerdutyapikey/mykey/g
```

Any idea why the environment variable `$PAGERDUTYAPIKEY` is rendering empty when i run through the userdata ?

Comment: Crossposted to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70423727/1030675).

Comment: As mentioned in comments on SO, `sudo` resets most of environment variables. Drop `sudo` from the user-data script, it runs as `root` anyway.

Comment: Dropping sudo worked! Thanks

Comment: @MervinHemaraju - if you post the answer as an answer here, you can mark this question as answered and save people the click through to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from the StackOverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423727/environment-variable-empty-in-bash-script

As answered by @chepner sudo does not preserve arbitrary environment variables by default for security reasons. So dropping sudo from the command helped me.

Comment: Please don't cross post your questions. Either delete your question here or on SO. IMO SO is a better fit for the question.